# Possible HTML encoding bug in the Android app achievements view

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

Consider the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30910070/2422776):

When I open the question in the android app its title displays the same way it displays in a normal browser:

```
what does “-&gt;” mean in swift when declaring functions?
```

However, when I see it in the achievements view, the HTML is decoded, and its displayed as

```
what does “->” mean in swift when declaring functions?
```

Technical details:
App version: 1.0.68
Android Version: 5.1.1
Phone model: Nexus 4

Screenshot, as requested:

> [image]

Comment: Whatever caused this appears to be fixed.